# animate width doesn't work properly in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

i have a problem with safari and chrome browser with this script. i can close sidebar in both browsers, but when i click to slide it open, sidebar opens transparent. everything works correctly and as it should in ff, opera and ie7+

any ideas?

```
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="et">
<head>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body, html {
      margin:0;
      background-color:#666;
    }

    .fixed {
      position:fixed;
      width:auto;
      height:100%;
    }

    .sidebar {
      float:left;
      width:300px;
      height:100%;
    }

    .header {
      float:left;
      width:300px;
      height:1200px;
      background-color:#d8d8d8;
    }

    .body {
      margin-left:600px;
      width:600px;
      background-color:red;
      height:2000px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /*$('.sidebar').addClass('closed');
      $('.sidebar').hide();
      $('.body').css('margin-left', 300);*/

      $('.close').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($('.sidebar').hasClass('closed')) {
          $('.sidebar').animate({ width : 'show'});
          $('.body').animate({ marginLeft : 600});
          $('.sidebar').removeClass('closed');
        } else {
          $('.sidebar').animate({ width : 'hide'});
          $('.body').animate({ marginLeft : 300});
          $('.sidebar').addClass('closed');
        }
      }); 
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="fixed">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="header"><a href="#" class="close">sule</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">body</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

As mentioned in the comment. You can use this version http://jsfiddle.net/QqGk6/ to solve your problem

---

Less hacky, but more verbose. Seems like this is a common WebKit Problem.

```
element = $('.header')[0];
var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
element.appendChild(n);
(function(){n.parentNode.removeChild(n)});
```

I found this article interesting: http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript

You could also try the "add/removeClass" method.

---

Seems like they dont want to repaint your .header .. Probably a bit hacky, but you can check this with

```
if($('.sidebar').hasClass('closed')) {
    $('.sidebar').animate({ width : 'show'});
    $('.header').append(" ");
    $('.body').animate({ marginLeft : 600});
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('closed');
} else {
    $('.sidebar').animate({ width : 'hide'});
    $('.body').animate({ marginLeft : 300});
    $('.sidebar').addClass('closed');
}
```

Hope this will help you find the Problem.

Comment: I noticed that it just wasn't repainting the header too. Was hoping to find a not so hacky way of accomplishing the repaint.

Comment: The whole problem is the Markup in this case. I rewrote it and it works fine now http://jsfiddle.net/QqGk6/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I actually refactored your markup and CSS. This is, in that case, what you want. Do you really need a fixed wrapper? Try fluid layouts :)

I posted the new html, css and js to fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/QqGk6/